# Radical Equation with Symmetry

Tags: closed-form, radical-equations

Is there an approach to solve the following radical equation in $x$?

$(P - 1)x 
   = QR\left( Q + \sigma \sqrt{Q^2 + x} \right)\left( R + sign(P-1) \sigma  \sqrt{R^2 + x} \right)$

We know $x\in (0,1)$. We also have $P, Q, R > 0$ and $\sigma \in \{-1,+1\}$.

Comment: It's going to be a bit messy, but what's wrong with good old squaring?

Comment: Wolfram alpha solves it.

Comment: It would. Mostly trusty calculator.